# How to start Android emulator via the command line on a Mac with Apple Silicon?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

## Problem

I get the following error when trying to start the Android emulator via the command line:

```
Could not launch '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64': No such file or directory
```

## Reproduction steps

1. Use a Mac with Apple Silicon.
2. Have an emulator already set up, for example Pixel 8 on Android 14 (API level 34).
3. Run command to start emulator with the emulator name, for example: `~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator @Pixel_8_API_34`.

Starting the emulator via the virtual device manager GUI has no problems.

## Investigation so far

### Possible cause

The error looks to be occurring because the **correct** location of the emulator binary is:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-aarch64/qemu-system-aarch64
```

Compare with the **incorrect** location:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64
```

### Information from `-verbose`

Running with `-verbose` gives the following information:

```
emulator:Android emulator version 26.0.3.0 (build_id 3965150)
emulator:Found AVD name 'Pixel_8_API_34'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: arm64
emulator:argv[0]: '~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator'; program directory: '~/Library/Android/sdk/tools'
emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (arm64 default)
emulator:  Found directory: ~/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-34/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/

emulator:try dir ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools
emulator:try dir ~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/
emulator:try dir ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64
emulator:Adding library search path: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator:Adding library search path: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator:Adding library search path: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator:Adding library search path: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator:Adding library search path: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Running :~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "@Pixel_8_API_34"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 ~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64 @Pixel_8_API_34 -verbose
Could not launch '~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-aarch64': No such file or directory
```

### System information

Android Studio:

- Version: Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1
- Runtime version: 17.0.9+0-17.0.9b1087.7-11185874 aarch64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Virtual device:

- avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 8 API 34
- AvdId: Pixel_8_API_34
- image.androidVersion.api: 34
- image.sysdir.1: system-images/android-34/google_apis_playstore/arm64-v8a/

### Information from documentation

I've looked at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) for starting the Android emulator on the command line but am not certain if there's an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies in the fact that you're using

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
```

which contains an outdated version of the emulator that no longer receives updates, ever since Google updated the Android SDK structure, and decided to put the emulator in a separate location from other tools.

You should be using this instead:

```
~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/emulator
```